# Which code comparison plugin does Stack Overflow use?

Tags: support, edits, revision-history

Which code comparison plugin does Stack Overflow use? Is that a custom build?

I checked out `google-diff-match-patch` but that isn't so friendly compared to the one Stack Overflow uses.

---

To clarify, I am talking about the code comparison on the website, for example:

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369

Comment: @juergend, strangely it does not appear to be listed there.

Comment: Perhaps this will help then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216326

Comment: @animuson *sigh*, so I think there's no plugin to do so...

Comment: I am a bit confused at using the term "plugin", as this sounds like there is some standard software running that people also use and write and use plugins with.

Comment: Yeah, the question in confusing because first it asks about *code* comparison and then goes on and gives an example of answer *text* comparison which is something different.

Comment: Come on, won't SE be kind enough to open source their diff engine? :) They seem to have a very cool algorithm that can handle huge code blocks - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/suggested-edit-diff-shows-different-results-depending-upon-mode/128705

Comment: @this.lau_ I highly doubt they would do so. A lot of questions on meta regarding how SO works either closed or without any normal answer. This is a business and no one want to share this.

Comment: [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) applies to morons posting on this website, not to those _running_ the site.

Comment: @devnull That's the spirit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by [@Animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262494/which-code-comparison-plugin-does-stack-overflow-use#comment52815_262494), Stackoverflow uses in-house diff engine..

> [Per
>   balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/suggested-edit-diff-shows-different-results-depending-upon-mode/128705#128705), Stack Exchange uses an in-house diff engine based on [a particular
>   implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11454/A-word-wise-HTML-text-compare-and-merge-engine)
>   of [Eugene Myers' O(ND) difference
>   algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11454/A-word-wise-HTML-text-compare-and-merge-engine),
>   with several enhancements to support more natural diffing.
>
> For brevity, I'll refer you to his [fairly detailed
>   post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/suggested-edit-diff-shows-different-results-depending-upon-mode/128705#128705)
>   for an indepth overview.

<sup>Quoting From : [What does Stack Overflow use for its community wiki edits comparison feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216324/what-does-stack-overflow-use-for-its-community-wiki-edits-comparison-feature/216326#216326)</sup>